# Write an Rcpp function to detect if a NumericMatrix has any NA values

Tags: r, matrix, rcpp

I want to write an Rcpp function with a NumericMatrix argument. It returns true if any of the matrix elements are NA, false otherwise. I tried looping is_na over all the columns but I am looking for a neater way. I am also concerned about speed.

```
bool check(NumericMatrix M){
n=M.ncol();
  for(int i=0; i < n; i ++){
  if(is_na( M(_,i) ){ return T;}
  } 
  return F;
}
```

Comment: Vectorized R operations are fast.  Try `any(is.na(M))` from R and profile it.

Comment: You are right. Now this check function is meant to be used within a larger Rcpp function. What's a good way of transporting any(is.na(M)) to Rcpp? Is looping is_na through the columns the way to go?

Comment: Have you found Rcpp sugar functions yet and checked there?  You may like what you find (and we have one small advantage that operators like `any(...)` can quit on first `TRUE`.  R will always run the full vector...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rcpp sugar can replicate the operation by combining `is_na()` and `any()`. `is_na()` will detect missing values and `any()` verifies a single value is `TRUE`. Note, to retrieve a boolean value, `any()` must be used with `is_true()`.

```cpp
#include<Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool contains_na(NumericMatrix M){
  return is_true(any(is_na(M)));
}
```

Test case:

```r
A = matrix(1:4, nrow = 2)
contains_na(A)
# [1] FALSE

M = matrix(c(1, 2, NA, 4), nrow = 2)
contains_na(M)
# [1] TRUE
```