# How do I check whether an IntegerVector contains NA values in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I wish to check that an Rcpp IntegerVector provided to a C++ function does not contain `NA` values.

Following [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199308/write-an-rcpp-function-to-detect-if-a-numericmatrix-has-any-na-values), I have written the below:

```cpp
IntegerMatrix stop_if_na(const IntegerVector I) {
  if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::IntegerVector::is_na(I)))) {
    Rcpp::stop("`I` contains NA values");
  }
```

But I see a compilation error:

```
note: candidate: 'template<bool NA, class T> bool Rcpp::is_na(const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA, T>&)'
      38 |  inline bool is_na( const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA,T>& x){
         |              ^~~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
   <file>.cpp:22:48 note:   'const IntegerVector' {aka 'const Rcpp::Vector<13, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>'} is not derived from 'const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA, T>'
      22 |   if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::is_na(I)))) {
         |                                            ^
```

When I remove `IntegerVector::` (as suggested by user20650 and Dirk  Eddelbuettel) I see

```
error:  matching function for call to 'is_na(const IntegerVector&)
      20 |   if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::is_na(I)
         |   

template argument deduction/substitution failed:
   <file>.cpp:20:48:note: 'const IntegerVector{aka 'const note: ndidate: 'template<bool NA, class T> bool Rcpp::is_na(const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA, T>&)
      38 |  inline bool is_nast Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA,T>& x){
         |              ^~~~~
   note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<file>.cpp:20:48:note: 'const IntegerVector{aka 'const Rcpp::Vector<13, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> is not derived from 'const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult<NA, T>
      20 |   if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::is_na(I)
         |                                            ^
```

(As the C++ function is exported from a package, I can't rely on the calling R function to perform this test.)

### `sessionInfo()` output

```
R Under development (unstable) (2022-07-19 r82607 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] htmlwidgets_1.5.4    compiler_4.3.0       microbenchmark_1.4.9 magrittr_2.0.3      
 [5] fastmap_1.1.0        cli_3.3.0            profvis_0.3.7        tools_4.3.0         
 [9] htmltools_0.5.3      rstudioapi_0.13      stringi_1.7.8        stringr_1.4.0       
[13] digest_0.6.29        rlang_1.0.4
```

`packageVersion("Rcpp")` = 1.0.9

Comment: Use `Rcpp::is_na(I)`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Looks like you never ever accept an answer to your questions. Net-net that sends a signal to maybe not spend time on your questions -- which may not be what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have only just seen your answer, but I've not accepted it yet as it doesn't seem to work on my machine.  I'll investigate further when I next have the opportunity.

Comment: Let us if we can help. What is below are very vanilla Rcpp invocations that should work everywhere.

Comment: Thanks.  I edited the question with the error I receive when removing `IntegerVector`.  The looping version via Hadley (or something similar) works – the sugar feels more elegant but perhaps I should settle for something I can get to work!

Comment: @MartinSmith; Does the minimal example at the end  of Drik's answer work for you? If not, it may be worth updating your question with the results of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Second the comment. What I show in my answer, and what I posted for the very reason of easy producibility, did of course work here.

Comment: Dirk's code snippet works if executed using `Rcpp::cppFunction`, but not if run as a void in `<file>.cpp`.  (` matching function for call to 'is_na(Rcpp::IntegerVector&)`) I'll add `sessionInfo()` now.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. Your session info doesn't mention Rcpp, but I am assuming it is up to date. Does `Rcpp::sourceCpp("dirksAnswer.cpp")` work in R release ( as opposed to unstable)?

Comment: " but not if run as a void in `<file>.cpp`." -- that is expected. Check our docs, we never claim you could just add content 'randomly' like this. You need to generate glue code, e.g. via `compileAttributes()` and `cppFunction()` and `sourceCpp()` do that for you.

Comment: Thanks – my `<file.cpp>` is part of a package, and I use `compileAttributes()` etc.  The suggestion to explore `sourceCpp()` led me to the issue: the <Rcpp/Lightest>header does not include the sugar function.  Doh!  Thanks both for your pointers.

Comment: Well yes: "Lightest".  Pick your weapons.  Sugar is awesome but has compile-time costs. And please note that your example _was never fully reproducible_ so you could have saved yourself a lot of running around by following standard [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) recommendations.  But very glad to hear you are sorted out now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is so core a feature that we had it more or less since day one, and I am a little surprised that you did not come across the very early Rcpp Gallery posts [Working with Missing Values](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-missing-values/) by Hadley from Dec 2012.

Note that the more interesting features are 'Sugar' functions:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("LogicalVector foo(NumericVector x) {return is_finite(x);}")
> foo(c(1.0, Inf, -Inf, NA, NaN, 42))
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
>
```

There are a few related predicates you may want to look into.

Your suggested function also works if you just remove the `::IntegerVector` in the call:

```
> Rcpp::cppFunction("void stop_if_na(const IntegerVector IV) {
+ if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::is_na(IV)))) {
+ Rcpp::stop(\"`I` contains NA values\");
+ }
+ }")
> stop_if_na(1:5)
> stop_if_na(c(1:5, NA, 7:9))
Error: `I` contains NA values
>
```

For ease of re-use my code snippet follows.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("LogicalVector foo(NumericVector x) { return is_finite(x); }")
foo(c(1.0, Inf, -Inf, NA, NaN, 42))


Rcpp::cppFunction("void stop_if_na(const IntegerVector IV) {
  if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::is_na(IV)))) {
    Rcpp::stop(\"`I` contains NA values\");
  }
}")
stop_if_na(1:5)
stop_if_na(c(1:5, NA, 7:9))
```

Answer (score 0):

What my question didn't stipulate, which turned out to be critical, was that I was using the `<Rcpp/Lightest>` header file, which does not contain the `is_na` macro; `<Rcpp/Lighter>` does.  I therefore met with success when updating to:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp/Lighter>  // NOT "Rcpp/Lightest"
using namespace Rcpp;

IntegerMatrix stop_if_na(const IntegerVector I) {
  if (Rcpp::is_true(Rcpp::any(Rcpp::IntegerVector::is_na(I)))) {
    Rcpp::stop("`I` contains NA values");
  }
  // Rest of function
}
```

Comment: I believe this to be documented too: Lightest != Sugar.